# Maximal partition

Tags: algorithm, partition, approximation

Given an integer *n*, and 2 real sequences {*a_1*, ..., *a_n*} and {*b_1*, ..., *b_n*}, with *a_i*, *b_i* > 0, for all *i*. For a given fixed *m* < *n* let {*P_1*, ..., *P_m*} be a partition of the set {1, ..., *n*} as in *P_1* U ... U *P_n* = {1, ..., *n*}, with the *P_i*'s pairwise disjoint (empty intersection). I wish to find a partition of size *m* that maximizes the expression

[image]

The number of partitions of the set is *n* choose *m*, prohibitively large to do by brute force. Is there an iterative or approximate solution that does better?

For insight into this problem the code block at the end solves via brute-force. For realistic size problems (*n* ~ 1e6, *k* ~ 20) it is unusable as is, but easily distrubuted.

**Edit**: Presorting *a*, *b* by the values of *a*^2/*b* always gives increasing partition indices:

```
a = rng.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=NUM_POINTS)
b = rng.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=NUM_POINTS)

ind = np.argsort(a/b)
(a,b) = (seq[ind] for seq in (a,b))
```

a sample run with

```
NUM_POINTS = 16
PARTITION_SIZE = 3
```

gives an optimal partition of

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

which is monotonic in the indices. I think I can prove this. If so, the brute-force search could be improved to *n* choose *k*-1 time, still long, but a significant savings.

```
 import numpy as np
 import multiprocessing
 import concurrent.futures
 from functools import partial
 from itertools import islice

 rng = np.random.RandomState(55)

 def knuth_partition(ns, m):
     def visit(n, a):
         ps = [[] for i in range(m)]
         for j in range(n):
             ps[a[j + 1]].append(ns[j])
         return ps

     def f(mu, nu, sigma, n, a):
         if mu == 2:
             yield visit(n, a)
         else:
             for v in f(mu - 1, nu - 1, (mu + sigma) % 2, n, a):
                 yield v
         if nu == mu + 1:
             a[mu] = mu - 1
             yield visit(n, a)
             while a[nu] > 0:
                 a[nu] = a[nu] - 1
                 yield visit(n, a)
         elif nu > mu + 1:
             if (mu + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                 a[nu - 1] = mu - 1
             else:
                 a[mu] = mu - 1
             if (a[nu] + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                 for v in b(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                     yield v
             else:
                 for v in f(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                     yield v
             while a[nu] > 0:
                 a[nu] = a[nu] - 1
                 if (a[nu] + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                     for v in b(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                         yield v
                 else:
                     for v in f(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                         yield v

     def b(mu, nu, sigma, n, a):
         if nu == mu + 1:
             while a[nu] < mu - 1:
                 yield visit(n, a)
                 a[nu] = a[nu] + 1
             yield visit(n, a)
             a[mu] = 0
         elif nu > mu + 1:
             if (a[nu] + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                 for v in f(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                     yield v
             else:
                 for v in b(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                     yield v
             while a[nu] < mu - 1:
                 a[nu] = a[nu] + 1
                 if (a[nu] + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                     for v in f(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                         yield v
                 else:
                     for v in b(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                         yield v
             if (mu + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                 a[nu - 1] = 0
             else:
                 a[mu] = 0
         if mu == 2:
             yield visit(n, a)
         else:
             for v in b(mu - 1, nu - 1, (mu + sigma) % 2, n, a):
                 yield v

     n = len(ns)
     a = [0] * (n + 1)
     for j in range(1, m + 1):
         a[n - m + j] = j - 1
     return f(m, n, 0, n, a)

 def Bell_n_k(n, k):
     ''' Number of partitions of {1,...,n} into
         k subsets, a restricted Bell number
     '''
     if (n == 0 or k == 0 or k > n): 
         return 0
     if (k == 1 or k == n): 
         return 1

     return (k * Bell_n_k(n - 1, k) + 
                 Bell_n_k(n - 1, k - 1)) 

 NUM_POINTS = 13
 PARTITION_SIZE = 4
 NUM_WORKERS = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
 INT_LIST= range(0, NUM_POINTS)
 REPORT_EACH = 10000

 partitions = knuth_partition(INT_LIST, PARTITION_SIZE)
 # Theoretical number of partitions, for accurate
 # division of labor
 num_partitions = Bell_n_k(NUM_POINTS, PARTITION_SIZE)
 bin_ends = list(range(0,num_partitions,int(num_partitions/NUM_WORKERS)))
 bin_ends = bin_ends + [num_partitions] if num_partitions/NUM_WORKERS else bin_ends
 islice_on = list(zip(bin_ends[:-1], bin_ends[1:]))

 # Have to consume it; can't split work on generator
 partitions = list(partitions)
 rng.shuffle(partitions)
 slices = [list(islice(partitions, *ind)) for ind in islice_on]
 return_values = [None] * len(slices)
 futures = [None] * len(slices)

 a = rng.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=NUM_POINTS)
 b = rng.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=NUM_POINTS)
 ind = np.argsort(a/b)
 (a,b) = (seq[ind] for seq in (a,b))

 def start_task():
     print('Starting ', multiprocessing.current_process().name)

 def _task(a, b, partitions, report_each=REPORT_EACH):
     max_sum = float('-inf')
     arg_max = -1
     for ind,part in enumerate(partitions):
         val = 0
         for p in part:
             val += sum(a[p])**2/sum(b[p])
         if val > max_sum:
             max_sum = val
             arg_max = part
         if not ind%report_each:
             print('Percent complete: {:.{prec}f}'.
                   format(100*len(slices)*ind/num_partitions, prec=2))
     return (max_sum, arg_max)

 def reduce(return_values):
     return max(return_values, key=lambda x: x[0])

 task = partial(_task, a, b)


 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
     for ind,slice in enumerate(slices):
         futures[ind] = executor.submit(task, slice)
         return_values[ind] = futures[ind].result()        


 reduce(return_values)
```

Comment: thx - edited the question.

Comment: could you give some sample expected Input/Output?

Comment: Added brute-force solution for further insight into behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to simply re-phrase the problem with sample input, let me know if I missed anything.

A = [1, 3, 2, 1, 4]
B = [2, 1, 5, 3, 1]
n = length(A) = length(B) = 5

We have two lists with positive integers.

We need to find a set of indices S (a subset of N = {1,2,3,..n}), let's assume it's {2,3,5}. Now, we get a new set S' = N - S = {1, 4}

For S and S', (sum(A[S]))^2/(sum(B[S'])) needs to be maximized.

As you said, the approximation solution will work too. One of the heuristics we can use is we need to choose such S so that the values of A list is high and values of B list is
low.

As we take the square of the sum on the subset of A, let's just sort A and choose a sublist so that we get the max score.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3])
B = np.array([3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1])

sorted_idx = sorted(range(len(A)), key=lambda k: A[k]) # also other sorting strategy can be used, A[k]/B[k]

A_p = A[sorted_idx]
B_p = B[sorted_idx]

max_s = 0
part_ans = -1

for i in range(len(A_p)):
  cur_s = (sum(A_p[:i])**2)/sum(B_p[i:])
  if cur_s >= max_s:
    print(cur_s)
    max_s = cur_s
    part_ans = i

print(f'The partitions are: {sorted_idx[:i]} and {sorted_idx[i:]}')
```

Comment: See edit above, I sorted on a/b. Partitions always have a monotonicity property.

Comment: No, A and B indices come from the same partition set, not S, S' as you have above. I am also asking about an arbitrary size partition, not nec. 2 subsets.